# Помощь со стилями CSS на примере схемы

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть данное изображение на сайте, как при наведение на определенные комнаты их подсвечивать ? Я понимаю, что нужно сделать position: absolute и displey: block, я не понимаю, как подсветить комнату использовать тег span и border или как ?

Comment: Подозреваю, здесь намного уместнее SVG

Answer (score 0):

Если бы я пытался решить данную проблему, то делал это через convas. Отслеживал бы положение курсора и рисовал линии для выделения комнаты.